# Installing Appcelerator Studio OS X El Capitan

Tags: ios, xcode, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I've been using Appcelerator Studio a lot, never seen this problem before. I recently did a fresh installation of OS X, then installing Xcode (7.3.1) and Command Line Tools for Xcode 7.3.1.

When installing Appcelerator Studio (build: 4.5.0.201602170821) everything is going great, the CLI gets installed. When starting up Appcelerator Studio, I have to configure SDKs, hence I am only interested in iOS at the moment, I uncheck Android in the Platform Configuration. The following is that Configuring SDK encountered a problem:

```
 An internal error occurred during: "Configuring SDK". java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I continuing, and go to Preferences>Studio>Platforms>iOS, where the iOS SDK home says Not specified, I click refresh - nothing happens. 
I run `xcode-select -p` and the correct path to Xcode Developer folder is printed.

Anyone having a clue of solving this? 
I've check all the version statuses, also tried to reinstall and deleting all information that can impact to this.

Comment: This seems like https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-322 and https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-8458. Please add your comments to the 2nd (open) one and apart from fixing the issue we'll have to make Studio more foolproof on this aspect as well.

Comment: Are you able to solve the problem? If not, drop a comment in (https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-8458), will get in touch with you to connect remotely to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Share the directory hierarchy where you have stored Android SDK and Platform screen folder. Also try to follow the guidelines of Titanium to integrate iOS, but remember to clean the hidden folders in root directory of your OS X system.

Comment: The thing is I'm not trying to get Android to work. I followed the guidelines and also tried with cleaning all hidden files also...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem might be with your Xcode. Are you having multiple Xcode's installed?

Use `sudo xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>` switch between Xcode's.

Then,run `appc ti info -t ios` and check whether CLI is able to identify the selected Xcode. If your Xcode is listed here, then studio should be able to identify it.

Comment: Appcelerator actually can work very well with multiple versions of Xcode so are you sure that can cause any issues?

Comment: You're right, it should work with multiple versions of Xcode. If there is any discrepancy they can switch between Xcode's and verify.